# How to use cobertura

Tags: cobertura

I have downloaded the zip file of version cobertura-1.9.4.1-bin. But i'm not able find how use the same with my project. Can you please help on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Janaki

Answer (score 1):

Try to read this: https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/FAQ

or https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/line-coverage-explained for examples

Do you have any specific questions?